# track heroku database changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My rails app is up and running.  It's crowdsourced so users can make changes to the database.  I'd like to be able to see myself what has been deleted or added.  Is there a way to view and track changes made to the database by others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gem like Paper Trail https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail to create a log of database updates.  It can log all updates to the database for your future review.